# Clink Clank Clunk

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, letters

> 1. Known as number one
> 2. Found on the edge of Trinidad and Denmark
> 3. Tool for filling six pockets

What's missing?

Hint 1:

> Alone, I am considered worthless, but together with my brothers and sisters, we can be a small fortune.

Hint 2:

> I'm kept safely in objects of all shapes and sizes, but my most commonly known home is inside the belly of an animal.

Comment: A bit of feedback: I think the original puzzle was far too underclued, especially since there's no way of knowing if you had gotten 1 of them wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know, based on humn's answer that:

> The letters are P,D,Q

And from the hint that:

> Together they are worth a small fortune

So what is missing is:

> N for nickel. The letters stand for Penny Dime, Quarter, Nickel, a small fortune.

Edit, finally figured out the last clue, LOL.

> Piggy bank. Nice one.

Answer (score 21):

> $\small\color{black}{\textsf{1. Known as number one}}$
>  
> **P**
>  –
>  [“pee”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pee)/urine,
>  often referred to as “number one”
>  in families with young children.
>  
>    
>  $\small\color{black}{\textsf{2. Found on the edge of Trinidad and Denmark}}$
>  
> **D**
>  –
>  At the trailing edge of “ Trinida***d*** ”
>  and the leading  edge of “***D***enmark.”
>  
>    
>  $\small\color{black}{\textsf{3. Tool for filling six pockets}}$
>  
> **Q**
>  –
>  [pool (pocket billiards)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(cue_sports))
>  “cue” stick.
>  
>    
>  $\color{black}{\textsf{4.}}$
>  $\textsf{Funniest classical composer never}$
>  
>
>  **Bach**
>  =
>  [P.D.Q. Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._D._Q._Bach)
>  (alter ego of Peter Shickele),
>  the least real and most hilarious musical offering
>  (21st child) of J.S. Bach.
>  
>    
>  P.D.Q. Bach’s oddly canted
>  [*Six Contrary
>    Dances*<sub>YOUTUBE</sub>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-ZCCbBpSw0),
>  for instance,
>  puzzled musicologists and enigmatologists alike,
>  until metrologists determined that his peg leg
>  was three full inches shorter than his natural leg.

This puzzle’s title, *Clink Clank Clunk*, would refer to...

> ...silly sound effects used in
>     many of P.D.Q. Bach’s compositions.

Comment: This sounds so hilarious to me. I'm looking forward to playing this.... for friends. Good answer and question.

Comment: +1 for 1,2,3 correct, the answer is incorrect, although that Bach piece is hilarious. There's no outside research that needs to be done for this solution - the answer is common knowledge. I'll put a hint in the question. and yes, the title does give a hint as well

Answer (score 4):

Known as number one

> I (roman numeral)

Found on the edge of Trinidad and Denmark

> D (Trinida**d**, **D**enmark

Tool for filling six pockets

> Q (Cue from Pool)

Potentially leaving

> P, for the [IDQP](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/safety/audit/Pages/idqp.aspx)?

Comment: +1, #2 and #3 are correct, and you have the correct train of thought in solving the puzzle, but #1 and the answer are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Known as number one

> Letter A?

#2 and #3 have already been found, which gives us

> ADQ .

I have no idea where this lead to, but the title of this puzzle make me think to

> smithing (sound of the hammer on the anvil).
>  This with humm's answer is making me thinking to "Between the hammer and the anvil" from Judas Priest, but probably no link with the solution.

But I don't know if that is the right path.

Comment: Good try, but #1 is incorrect